# Combining std::strings and C-Strings causes buffer overrun

Tags: c++, winapi, cstring

I am attempting to make a function that will make combining C Strings and `std::string`s a little easier in my C++ WinAPI Application.

So instead of doing this:

```
TCHAR res[MAX_PATH];
_stprintf(res, _T("In functionX(): error occured where the variable values are %d, %u, %s, %c"), myInt, myUnsignedInt, myStr.c_str(), myChar);
MessageBox(NULL, res, _T("Error Occurred"), MB_OK);
```

I just have to do this(which makes it a little easier to merge different string types because I don't have to keep declaring TCHAR arrays everywhere):

```
tstring res = concat(_T("In functionX(): error occured with the variable values %d, %u, %s, %c"), myInt, myUnsignedInt, myStr.c_str(), myChar);
MessageBox(NULL, (LPTSTR)res.c_str(), _T("Error Occurred"), MB_OK);
```

**My Problem:** My function *concat();* fails when I pass more than 1 variable inside the parameter *format* and I dont know why?

```
// The following function call causes the error
tstring ou = concat(_T("In functionX(): Failed to create temp file - %s - %s\r\n"), (LPTSTR)tempFileRootDir.c_str(), tempFile); 

tstring WinFile::concat( TCHAR* strFormat, TCHAR* format, ... )
{
    // tstring is either a std::string or std::wstring depending on whether unicode is used
    // Post: Wrapper function to easily merge C++ strings with C Strings

    va_list arguments;
    va_start(arguments, format);
    TCHAR res[MAX_PATH];
    _stprintf(res, strFormat, format); 
    return tstring(res);
}
```

The error that occurs when I run the function in Microsoft Visual C++ is:

> A buffer overrun has occurred in Application.exe which has
>   corrupted the program's internal state. Press Break to debug the
>   program or Continue to terminate the program.
>
> For more details please see Help topic 'How to debug Buffer Overrun
>   Issues'.

Comment: Why are you declaring res to have MAX_PATH characters?  You aren't copying a path to it.  At a guess, I'd say you're trying to write more than MAX_PATH characters to res.

Comment: As an option you can use ATL::CString. It has Format method.

Comment: Any particular reason for uppercasing `STD`? That usually means sexually transmitted disease, doesn't it? The C++ standard library namespace is `std`, in lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your varargs handling is a bit off.  And yes, by writing to a fixed size buffer, you're asking for a stack overflow.

To correct the first, you'll need to use a varargs-accepting version of printf.  For the second, you should count before you print:

```
tstring WinFile::concat( TCHAR const * strFormat, ... )
{
    va_list args;

    // Determine how much space to reserve.
    va_start(args, strFormat);
    size_t msg_len=_vsctprintf(strFormat, args);
    va_end(args);

    // Reserve space on heap.
    //
    // "_vscprintf returns the number of characters that would be generated
    // if the string pointed to by the list of arguments was printed ... 
    // [and] does not include the terminating null character."
    //
    // So we add space for a terminating null.
    std::vector<TCHAR> writebuffer(1+msg_len);

    // perform formatting
    va_start(args, strFormat);
    _vstprintf(&writebuffer[0], strFormat, args);
    va_end(args);

    // return a copy as a tstring.
    return tstring(&writebuffer[0], &writebuffer[msg_len]);
}
```

Comment: I think `concat` as a name is a bit misleading.  Perhaps `WinFile::format_msg`?

Comment: thanks for the teaching. I get an error declaring writebuffer: "Expression must have a constant value". Is my only solution to declare a vector or use a tstring instead?

Comment: Are dynamically sized arrays not standard C++ yet?  Probably best to just use a `std::vector` then.  In particular, trying to write directly into a `tstring` with a c-style function (`_vstprintf`) is almost certainly a bad idea.  I've modified my answer accordingly.